# How do I query multiple corresponding values from MySQL and add them together easily?

Tags: php, mysql

My database table holds width measurements for a specific font file.  I'm trying to query the database for Letter_Box_Width for each corresponding letter within my $word variable and add them together to get a $total_word_box_width.

Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to easily query for multiple corresponding values and then add these values together afterward.  I'm thinking I split $word, into an array... but then I'm unclear on how to query each value within the array.  Will I have to do a separate query for each array value?

```
$word = "CHAD";

$array_to_query = str_split($word);
```

My table of data:

[image: Font Table]

The result of $total_word_box_width using my example "CHAD" should result in a value of 4500.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: for the word  "chad" what values are you summing?

Comment: Letter_Box_Width

Comment: `select sum(Letter_Box_Width) from XXX  where Alpha in ('c','h','a','d');` ///you can make the in sting with `implode()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do what you want. I'm assuming you're using `mysqli` and you have a database connection in `$conn` but that should be easy enough to change to what you actually have.

```
$word = 'chad';
$letters = array_unique(str_split(strtoupper($word)));
$query = "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Alpha) AS Alpha,
                 GROUP_CONCAT(Letter_Box_Width) AS Letter_Box_Width
          FROM letters 
          WHERE Alpha IN ('" . implode("','", $letters) . "')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("unable to query database!");
if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $widths = array_combine(explode(',', $row['Alpha']), explode(',', $row['Letter_Box_Width']));
    $total_word_box_width = 0;
    foreach (str_split(strtoupper($word)) as $letter) {
        $total_word_box_width += $widths[$letter];
    }
}
echo $total_word_box_width;
```

I've included a call to `strtoupper` so that it doesn't matter if your word is in upper or lower case. If in fact you have separate entries in your table for upper and lower case characters, you would remove that call in the places it occurs i.e.

```
$letters = array_unique(str_split($word));
    foreach (str_split($word) as $letter) {
```

Comment: Hi.  I'm getting a "PHP Notice:  Undefined index: c " for this line.. $total_word_box_width += $widths[$letter];    This is happening for each letter.

Comment: If you don't have lowercase letters in the table, you need to leave the calls to `strtoupper` in place.

Comment: Do you have lowercase letters in the table?

Comment: Yes, I have lowercase letters, and also spaces, apostrophes, and hyphens...

Comment: I'm confused. With the `strtoupper` removed it should work. Can you tell me what's in `$query` and `$row`?

Comment: $query = "SELECT Alpha, Letter_Box_Width
          FROM Font_Krinkes
          WHERE Alpha IN ('" . implode("','", $letters) . "')";
$result = mysqli_query($con2, $query) or die("unable to query database!");


if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

Comment: Sorry I meant the actual values of those variables i.e. output from `echo $query; print_r($row);`

Comment: To double check I was getting values back, I temporarily replaced your next block of code with a standard while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) and it outputs the cooresponding values just fine.  So I am getting correct values....

Comment: Just noticed you're not using `GROUP_CONCAT`. My code relies on you doing that to get all the data in one row that can then be used to make up the `$widths` array.

Comment: I removed that because of these errors:  Undefined index: Alpha  AND Undefined index: Letter_Box_Width   When I removed, they went away, but the other PHP Notice:  Undefined index errors remain, with or without GROUP_CONCAT

Comment: I've fixed the query to resolve the `Undefined index` errors related to the `GROUP_CONCAT`. The values just needed to be aliased appropriately.

Comment: Great! Sorry it took a while - it's hard to get code exactly right when you don't have access to the tables...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181518/discussion-between-wyatt-jackson-and-nick).

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT SUM(Letter_Box_Width) FROM <table_name> WHERE Alpha IN ("C", "H", "A", "D")`

Does this not work?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a SQL aggregate function - thankfully the SQL specification contains just the one to suit your needs.

Without knowing your exact database system, I can't be sure of the specific code, but try something like the following :

```
SELECT SUM(Letter_Box_Width)
FROM <your table name>
WHERE Alpha in ('C', 'H', 'A', 'D')
```

How you parameterise the query so you can reuse it with other letter values also depends on your platform, but the use of SUM() should solve the heart of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
SELECT Alpha, Letter_Box_Width FROM table WHERE Alpha IN ('C', 'H', 'A', 'D')
```

Then create an array with Alpha as key and calculate the Sum of Letter_Box_Width.

In this particular example, you can also calculate the SUM in MySQL:

```
SELECT SUM(Letter_Box_Width) FROM table WHERE Alpha IN ('C', 'H', 'A', 'D')
```

But this won't work if the same letter occurs more than once, like HELLO, this will count the letter 'L' only once.

In other words,

```
SELECT SUM(Letter_Box_Width) FROM table WHERE Alpha IN ('H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O')
```

is the same as

```
SELECT SUM(Letter_Box_Width) FROM table WHERE Alpha IN ('H', 'E', 'L', 'O')
```